# Accessing PHP Pages URL?

Tags: php, url, redirect

I am recently working on a php project. I created the template for my site and design the pages. However, the navigation between pages is like the following:

`http://localhost:81/x/y/index.php` and when I want to navigate to another page the URL will be like: `http://localhost:81/x/y/second.php`

how can I make the following URL takes me to the second.php page?

```
http://localhost:81/x/y/index.php?page=second
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need a framework.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am misunderstanding something, put this at the top of the index.php page:

```
<?php
if($_GET['page'] == "second")
{
    $newURL = 'http://localhost:81/x/y/second.php';
    header('Location: ' . $newURL);
}
?>
```

See [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: what if i have 8 pages and you can access them from any page. This solution will be repeated 8 times in each page. Am I right?

Comment: Then put the code in one library file and call include() to include it in each page, so you don't have to rewrite it 8x.

Comment: or     <?php
    if (isset($_GET['page'])
    {
        if(htmlspecialchars($_GET['page'])=='second')
        {
            include('second.php')
            return;
        }
    }
    ?>

Answer (score 1):

I would add a bit more to it to make it secure but the simple answer would be...

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])
{
    require '/path/to/folder/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php';
}
```

If it is a redirection that you want, you could also do.

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])
{
    header('Location: ' . $_GET['page'] . '.php');
}
```

Comment: I understood that by using $_GET['page'] you will get second and then you concatenate it with php. But I did not understand where to use this code

Comment: Yep, that way you don't have to add an if block for each page you want to access. You would just insert the code at the top of index.php, or preferably as the only code in index.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this Rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^x/y/index.php?page=(.*)$ http://localhost:81/x/y/$1.php [R=301,L]
```